# Angular 6 angular.json add ssl in configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular6

I want to serve my application though SSL previously I had this script:

```
ng serve --ssl --ssl-key "pathtokey\key.crt"
```

I want to add SSL in the new angular.json but when i try to add it i got the error:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
 Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(ssl).
```

What is the proper way to use SSL with angular cli 6?

Comment: This example schema json might helps you. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L929-L941

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In angular.json:

```
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build",
        "ssl": true,
        "sslKey": "path to .key",
        "sslCert": "path to .crt"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice. Somewhere I read if we do ssl true angular will create key, certificates for you. Where can I see the file? In which directory?

Answer (score 2):

ANGULAR 6 REQUIRES YOU TO DEFINE THE PARAMS: *--ssl-key & --ssl-cert*

Create or get trusted certificate key and cert files and place it in C:\certificates\

```
ng serve --ssl --ssl-key c:\\certificates\\server.key  --ssl-cert c:\\certificates\\server.crt
```