# CORS in angular and node application not working

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, cors, microsoft-edge

I am facing some problems in my (Dockerized) Angular application.
During the loading on Edge/Firefox of my angular application all Request (RestApi) needed to fill my homepage don't arrive to my application.  If I load the same page with Chrome all requests arrived and the page is then filled.

The `server.js` of my Angular application is:

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');
    var https = require('https');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var fs = require('fs');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    var env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

    // Node express server setup.
    var app = express();
    app.set('port', 4200);   
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended : true
    }));
    app.use(express.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies 


        var server = https.createServer(proxyOption, app);
        server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
            console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
        });

        // redirect requests from HTTP to HTTPS
        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            console.log('Redirect HTTP request to https://' + req.headers['host'] + req.url);
            res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
            res.end();
        }).listen(80);
```

**Is this a problem of CORS doesn't working properly?**
I have also seen that is suggested to put the following value in the `polyfills.ts` file:

```js
    -----> (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

**Microsoft Edge**
Here you can see that on **Edge** the same request loaded is not working and the header is empty, that sounds strange
[image]
**Edge Console**:
[image]

**On Chrome** :
[image]

**Firefox**:
[image]

Why Access-Control-Allow-Headers are only in Chrome and not present in Firefox? (same page)

Why the following code is not visible when I load with Edge/Firefox?

```
app.all("/db/config", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method + ' ' + req.url);             <--- Visible only with Chrome
    processDbRequest(req, res, Config);
});
```

I am starting the application with the following command:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 443 --public-host IP --ssl --ssl-key /run/secrets/secret.key --ssl-cert /run/secrets/secret.cert --proxy-config server.js --prod
```

What do you think?
Tks

Anyhow on Chrome there is the section (CORS) not visible in the headers of Edge/Firefox.
[image]

**UPDATE**
The Error visible in EDGE are:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null"
[object Error]: {description: "Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null", message: "Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null", promise: Object, rejection: Object, stack: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null at M (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:14070) at M (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:13634) at Anonymous function (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:14864) at t.prototype.invokeTask (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:8720) at onInvokeTask (https://<IP>/main.962c274fd5e7aea50f8c.js:1:422471) at t.prototype.invokeTask (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:8720) at e.prototype.runTask (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:4000) at g (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:11104) at e.invokeTask (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:9950) at m (https://<IP>/polyfills.126a602ce79d269ee3a3.js:1:23265)"...}
```

Here package.json configuration:

```
{
  "name": "elg-dash",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=dev && ng serve --port 3000 --proxy-config server.js ",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@eds/vanilla": "^3.4.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "d3": "^5.12.0",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.4.1",
    "microsoft-adal-angular6": "^1.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.5",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.5.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

**SMALL UPDATE**

It seems that the same angular application works in Firefox with the following version : **72.0.1 (64-bit)**, the same app doesn't work on the **Linux Version 72.0.1 (64-bit)**.

Comment: CORS errors are easy to spot when you look in the Network tab of the developer tools in Edge. Do you see any errors there? Or in the Console tab?

Comment: check the Network tab or console tab

Comment: hi @HereticMonkey I have updated the post with some images

Comment: The response is 200 OK, so it's unlikely a CORS error (those generally have a status of 0).

Comment: @HereticMonkey the weird think is that I am not able to see the request header like you can see on Chrome (on Edge)

Comment: What do you mean by "During the boot phase"?

Comment: @nycynik right, I wanted to say during the loading of the home page of my angular application.

Comment: @HereticMonkey on Firefox as you can see in the updated post I can't see in the Header section the one used and visible with Chrome related Access-Control-Allow-Headers, don't you think is related to CORS then?

Comment: You're showing the Request headers in the Firefox screenshot. The Access-Control-* headers are Response headers. I've actually got some paying work to do, so apologies if I disappear.

Comment: Besides the Network tab, have you checked the console on Edge? Is there any error in console? What is the difference of the page showing between Edge and Chrome? It could be better if you provide a [minimal sample and steps to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue. So that we can test and have a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Prisco It is hard to say it is CORS because in that case you cannot get 200 OK status.
Your image do not give any hint much. I GUESS some scenarios happened to you base on my experience that I faced same issue before with Angular on server using JBOSS (not docker).

1. Check the response and see there is the message like `failed to load...` or not?
   If yes, then something block your response. It could be your web server and could be your computer software like antivirus.
2. Check your page look like? Empty page? If Yes, It is because your front-end configuration like polyfill and browserlist.
3. Compare line by line to see different between Chrome and Edge to see any different and google it.
4. Could you try to deploy your project without docker to see it work or not. If it is working, then your docker configuration have issue.

Comment: Related the GET request on Firefox browser I can see SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN in the Security Tab, not visible on Edge

Comment: @Prisco Yes SSL is also the one who can block your response. just allow your page from icon on address or use `http`.

Comment: hi @Hoang, I need to use https, it seems something is blocking the request because in my angular application I don't receive any RestAPI coming once loading the page, instead if I load the same page with Chrome I can see many get request arriving. It seems the comunication between Server and Proxy it is not working properly :-(

Comment: Did you add the SSL certificate for your application? You can get some hints from here https://www.wikihow.com/Install-an-SSL-Certificate in case of not installing SSL certificate

Comment: yes I am using a certificate and starting my application:

ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 443 --public-host <IP> --ssl --ssl-key /run/secrets/secret.key --ssl-cert /run/secrets/secret.cert --proxy-config server.js --pro
d

Comment: still not working by that command line? Could you try to add it to `angular.json` like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881328/angular-6-angular-json-add-ssl-in-configuration

Comment: How is possible that I can't see coming request in my application , (log below) while on Chrome the request is tracked :-( 


app.all("/db/config", function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.method + ' ' + req.url);
 processDbRequest(req, res, Config);
});

Comment: I have updated the question by putting the error visible in EDGE.

Comment: You can also try to add the website to the Trusted site list to see if it helps. Also try to add `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');` in `app.use()`. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-the-express-js-framework-o) and [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server) for more information.